# MySQL data type for custom GUID

Tags: mysql

System generating a guid like:

```
mast_pv3qtYWmLegFP95xJNRz82k17cB46EH
```

Their length is always under 40 characters.

What would be the best data type to store and index them?

EDIT: "index" being the most important factor of the storage type.

Comment: I suggest you can use VARCHAR datatype.

Comment: The question you reference as already answered is nothing like the question I asked. I have a set character length that is alphanumeric (without special characters) and I wish to index the column.

Comment: The uplicate topic does answer your question because the question and the answers are about what is the appropriate data type for certain strings. Your guid is a string, there is frankly nothing special about it. You are apparently overthinking this.

Comment: What you show is not a GUID, don't overload terms for different things.